# Вывод определенного количества элементов списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, коллекции

Есть список, с `N` элементов. Как вывести все элементы по `M` элементов за раз? `M<N`. То есть, допустим `a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, а на выходе я хочу получить

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например, используя функцию [range(start, stop[, step])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range). У нее третий параметр шаг.

Код:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
k = 3
for i in range(0, len(a), k):
    print(a[i:i+k])
```

Консоль:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7]
```

---

Чтобы формат вывода был как в вопросе:

```
for i in range(0, len(a), k):
    row = a[i:i+k]
    print(', '.join(map(str, row)))
```

Comment: Спасибо, ответ мне подходит

Comment: Раз подходит, примите ответ )